# How to specify parameter value for stored procedure in SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, parameters, sqldatasource

Being new to using the declarative syntax of SqlDataSource I am trying to figure out a way to set the value of a parameter to a stored procedure. I have a Client_ID that is passed via the Request Object and I need to set the Client_ID before the stored procedure of the SqlDataSource is executed.

I have a couple of questions.

1. Does the stored procedure parameter have to be predefined in the ASPX markup or can it be added dynamically in the code-behind?
2. Would anyone have an example that demonstrates the SqlDataSource markup with a stored procedure and parameter as well as setting that parameter value in code-behind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With .net 4 framework you can ...

1.It can be added dynamically, but you would have to provide your own code expression builder (for further info [see here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx))
1.1 You can also use different parameter to achieve same goal, like :

[image]

2.

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:yourConnectionString %>" 
  SelectCommand="YourStoreProcedure" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter Name="yourParameterName" ControlID="controlThatHoldsParameterValue" PropertyName="Text" />
  </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly thorough example of using parameterized queries (Stored Procedure and Text) with SqlDataSource, including programmatically setting parameters. [ASP.NET - Using Parameterized Queries with the SqlDataSource](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ADSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ADConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="GetProfile" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="InputTextBox" Name="Host" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

GetProfile is the stored proc name and Host is parameter name, which is retreived from a texbox called InputTextBox