# using stored procedure in code behind to load infragistics grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, infragistics

I have a infragistics grid with auto generated columns how can i assign a strored proc result to it from code behind

```
      <ig:WebScriptManager ID="WebScriptManager1" runat="server"></ig:WebScriptManager>
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="EntityGrid" runat="server"  Width="100%">
    <Behaviors>
        <ig:Sorting>
        </ig:Sorting>
    </Behaviors>
</ig:WebDataGrid>
```

code behind is

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EntityName.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string @RegardingObjectName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiveLeaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "p_DataList_ByRegardingObject";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegardingObjectName", @RegardingObjectName);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {              
            con.Open();
            EntityGrid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            EntityGrid.DataBind();
```

i need to passin entity as parameter to stored proc. how can i do that here?

i am getting reader closed error

Comment: does the query return any rows? can you also paste the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a  [ControlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx) to `SelectParameters`

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="entityId" 
ControlID="DropDownList1" 
PropertyName="SelectedItem" Type="String" />
```

Also see this question [How to specify parameter value for stored procedure in SqlDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326113/how-to-specify-parameter-value-for-stored-procedure-in-sqldatasource)

**Edit** you can use the Selecting event as shown here

[Writing a SQLdatasource in code behind in C# to use a code behind value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048983/writing-a-sqldatasource-in-code-behind-in-c-sharp-to-use-a-code-behind-value?rq=1)

You can also add a select parameter as

```
EntityGrid.SelectParameters.Add("entityId", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Just rename "entityId" to the name of parameter to be used with SP

**Edit2** :

Instead of

```
EntityGrid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            EntityGrid.DataBind();
```

Try this

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    using (reader)
    {
      DataTable table = new DataTable();
      table.Load(reader);
      EntityGrid.DataSource = table;
    }
```

See this link for more :
http://mentaljetsam.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/loading-an-sqldatareader-into-a-datagridview/

Comment: i want to do it from code behind in the.cs file as the this grid will get data only when selected index changed event is fired for a drop down

Comment: Thanks for help amitd. iam trying something like this

Comment: Invalid object name 't_Select'. i am getting this error when i try it